# Custom UITableViewCell information needed in a custom UIView of the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, subclass

I currently have a tableview with camera information.
In my tableview I would like to add a live view of the camera.

I am needing to subclass the live view due to different camera SDKs...

My question is, how can I send the camera data from the tableviewcell to the custom UIView (which will be the live camera feed)?

I have a array of custom objects (each object contains ip-addresses and ports used to connect to the camera locally or remotely) and i would like to send this object to the subview.

My tableviewcell looks as follows (the blue block is where i will show the camera, which is 3rd party security cameras):

[image]

And I want to show the next view in the blue block above, however there will be a camera feed in this view. This view connects to the different cameras (will be multiple UIView implementations on what to use due to the different cameras...)

[image]

I basically would like to know how to send [MyTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] to the relevant UIView for processing and then viewing the feed from that camera...

Note: I have the camera implemented already, I just need it in the tableview for quick-viewing...

Thank you for any help...

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information... What camera data? Different data for each row, with different live feeds in each row? Try laying out what you want to achieve and post an image with explanations of each element and descriptions of what you want to happen.

Comment: @DonMag, Hope the edit makes it more understandable

Comment: Have you made the view a subview of the cell? If so, why can't you set the information just like setting any information in a cell? If it's *not* inside the cell, where is it?

Comment: @DonMag, Well the idea is to put it inside the cell, however the view will have different implementations... for each of the different cameras we use... If I however understand you correctly, I should add properties in the header of the view's class and set the properties...

Comment: Well, yes... just as you (simply) put different text into the Label of the cell, you would assign the proper connection values for the `UIImageView`. My assumption is that you have a subclass which would include an image view plus any other elements needed to make it a "camera view".

Comment: @DonMag thanx helped alot